# Changing date within selection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro to change dates in selected range. It works just fine, but when within selection there is cell with non-date value ( ex. "abcdef" or cell is empty) and I run macro it converts this non-date value into date. How should I fix it?

Current code:

```
Sub adddate()
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection

For Each cell In Selection
If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
Selection.Cells = DateAdd("d", 28, CDate(cell))
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub adddate()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Selection
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then cell = DateAdd("d", 28, CDate(cell))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup :) That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!                   Could you please explain to me why "selection.cells " did not work?

Comment: `Selection.Cells` returns ALL cells in the selection, thus bringing along those that wouldn't pass the `If IsDate` check, too! Since you're looping through and checking every single `cell` of `Selection`, then stick to it!

Comment: Thanks mate. I really appreciate that.